# SPD Workflows and RegEx

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, regex

Is it possible to use a regular expression in an SPD workflow?  I am trying to use the for-each hack to take a list of semicolon delimited values and create a new form for each of them, but I can't figure out how to select the individual values (they are not of uniform length).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use any 3rd party workflow products, such as Nintex/K2 or others, you would either need to develop your own activities or use any of the ones available freely (e.g. RegEx based activity) - such http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2011/02/just-released-advanced-workflow-actions.html

Also some other example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/05/14/create-compact-and-powerful-conditions-in-your-workflows.aspx

Comment: I have seen the second post you mentioned.  This offers some hope, but it only works for matching.  I need something that can do a substitution, or possibly give me an index so that I can use substring to remove the values I need.  Also, I'd like to be able to trim whitespace from the ends, but not the middle.